# showing the message “Just Another WordPress Site” when when the site link is shared

Tags: wordpress

I have already change the tagline, Like photos:
[image]
[image]

but when the link is shared, the tagline showed is the old one (“Just Another WordPress Site”).
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add some other tagline words instead of leaving them blank.

Clear the cache in the browser, in the system, and on the website if it has any cache plugins.

Comment: I added some other tagline words, and it shows in the title of browser tab. but when I want to share the site link, showing the message “Just Another WordPress Site”

Comment: Have you found the solution? If not try to add any SEO plugins, they will allow you to add custom meta titles to every page. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx. I added the Yoast Seo. and it solved my problem